# How to check if string in nsdictionary is null

Tags: iphone, ios, twitter, nsdictionary

I'm working on a twitter app and trying to implement tweet location. All I want is to display name of the country and display it on the map if tweet has location. But whatever I've tried it always displays country of the first tweet or if it's null the app crashes. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone help? Thank you!
Here's my code:

```
   // LOCATION
   for (NSDictionary *dic in self.dataSource)
    {
        NSString *str = [dic valueForKeyPath:@"place.name"];
        if(str)
        {
            cell.button.hidden = NO;
            cell.location.text = [dic valueForKeyPath:@"place.full_name"];
            self.coordinates = [dic valueForKeyPath:@"geo.coordinates"];
            break;
        } else {
            cell.button.hidden = YES;
            cell.location.hidden = YES;
            break;
        }

    }
```

And this is the NSLog output:

```
  2013-08-20 00:04:42.269 TwitterApplication[10011:c07] <null>
  2013-08-20 00:04:42.269 TwitterApplication[10011:c07] Downtown
  2013-08-20 00:04:42.269 TwitterApplication[10011:c07] <null>
  2013-08-20 00:04:42.270 TwitterApplication[10011:c07] Moscow
  2013-08-20 00:04:42.270 TwitterApplication[10011:c07] Брянск
  2013-08-20 00:04:42.270 TwitterApplication[10011:c07] <null>
  2013-08-20 00:04:42.271 TwitterApplication[10011:c07] Брянск
  2013-08-20 00:04:42.271 TwitterApplication[10011:c07] <null>
  2013-08-20 00:04:42.271 TwitterApplication[10011:c07] <null>
  2013-08-20 00:04:42.272 TwitterApplication[10011:c07] <null>
  2013-08-20 00:04:42.272 TwitterApplication[10011:c07] <null>
  2013-08-20 00:04:42.272 TwitterApplication[10011:c07] <null>
  2013-08-20 00:04:42.273 TwitterApplication[10011:c07] <null>
  2013-08-20 00:04:42.273 TwitterApplication[10011:c07] <null>
```

Comment: What code is producing that log?

Comment: name of the city if tweet has location, and null if has not got.

Comment: Show the code for it and how it relates to the code you have shown.

Comment: it was like this:  for (NSDictionary *dic in self.dataSource)
    {
        NSString *str = [dic valueForKeyPath:@"place.name"];
       NSLog(@"%@", str);
    }                                                                     I just wanted to make sure that i get city name.

Comment: As you said that this str may be null. Try using if([str isEqualToString:@""]).

Answer (score 0):

why do you check value for @"place.name" and then use @"place.full_name"? maybe this is the problem.

and I think you have to check @"geo.coordinates" value before using it.

try to change if statement to `if(str && str.lengh)`

and change `NSString *str = [dic valueForKeyPath:@"place.name"];`
to `NSString *str = [[dic valueForKeyPath:@"place.name"] lastObject];` because valueForKeyPath returns an array.

Comment: unfortunately not, I think the problem is connected with if, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Blaze but what is the point to check one value and to use another?

Comment: it was a mistake, I change to @"place.name"

Comment: error, NSNull length in tweets without location. And i have really strange output. seems like it remember the first value of str and didn't change during the cycle.

Comment: I use SLRequest to twitter api, it's plenty of code. I did as you told me, but it's error again: '-[NSNull lastObject]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1664678'

Comment: it just means that this array is nil. check nil, then get lastObject